# python meaning of method sum with use of sigma and pair

Tags: python, sum, alignment, bioinformatics

i'm trying to understand a code available on the internet

but i'm new to python, and could not get this line of code:

```
score = sum([-sigma if '-' in pair else scoring_matrix[pair] for pair in zip(v_aligned, w_aligned)])
```

i know method sum, as individual method 
but i don't understand what is happening inside the brackets

v_aligned, w_aligned are two aligned strings, for example if v=PLEASANTLY and w=MEANLY

v_aligned= LEASNT-LY
w_aligned= MEA-N-LY-

scoring_matrix is BLOSUM62

sigma=5

Comment: Then why don't you execute the commands separately and print the result? You should start from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first talk about that zip in you expression
It will 'pair' values from your two variables, meaning it will return a zip object that if you iterate through, will return sth like this ('L', 'M'), ('E', 'E'), ('A', 'A'), ('S', '-') and so on.
As you can see it goes through the letters of your 'words' and matches one letter from the first word to another 'character' from your second word.

That for loop will go step by step through every tuple that you gave it through that zip object and `pair` refers to that current tuple.

No then we have that `-sigm if '-' in pair else scoring_matrix[pair]`

It's simple - that's a condition that says: if '-' is in the current pair, so for example let's take ('L', 'M'), then put -sigma in this table, if it's not, then put the result of scrring_matrix[pair] there. As you can see '-' is not in ('L', 'M') so it'll put scoring_matrix[pair] there.